# Multiple Custom field in paypal notify url form

Tags: php, paypal

Paypal have CUSTOM param in its API... I want multi-dimension array pass in CUSTOM field...

```
  <form id="paypal_form" action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@paypal.com">
    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hot Sauce-12 oz. Bottle">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <!-- Prompt buyers to enter their desired quantities. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.myurl.com" />
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online" />
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="custom[]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="11" name="custom[]" />
  </form>
```

its working fine with single custom field but multi custom field is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should  pass all values like 1,2,3,4,5,6....

return url  you will get custom string and convert it to array of string